# jQuery animated page scroll with offset for fixed header blinks faded content

Tags: jquery, navigation, scroll, jquery-animate

I've got a fixed header/navigation on my site, which the page scrolls under (similar to Twitter). I'm trying to get it to smoothly scroll to articles within the page, while accounting for the height of the header, as not to cover up the top portion of the articles.

I think I've got the header height offset going, but the scroll is pretty choppy and inconsistent, and all the content with faded opacity blinks on when the navigation is used.

please see a test here: http://sketch.ryantroyford.com/newSite/testSite.html

Any idea what the problem could be? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Using this code found here http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/ -- you can adjust the offset as follows:

```
 $('html, body').stop().animate({
     scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top-150)
    }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
```

Note: the -150, adjust that number to reflect the size of your fixed header.

Answer (score 0):

Use the easing plugin for jQuery and the script located here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/

That will fix the choppy scrolling and blinking, but I'm working on the offset for the fixed header. I was just looking for the solution now and that's what brought me here.